# I got a warning "A batch with no more than one sample ---" when try to predict a single image using Resnet50 with Chainer

Tags: chainer

I got a warning "A batch with no more than one sample has been given to F.batch_normalization. F.batch_normalization will always output a zero tensor for such batches" when trying to predict a single a image.

I am using Resnet50 model (binary classification output) with Chainer, when training, the accuracy of both train and test set is > 98%. But when i tried to predict a single image, the accuracy is only about 50%.

I guess I have to predict images in batch (because Batch Normalization) to avoid warning and get high accuracy, right? Is it possible  to predict single image?

P/s : I tried chainer.using_config('train', False) in prediction script but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you set `chainer.config.train = False` correctly? Note that `chainer.using_config` is a context manager.

```
with chainer.using_config('train', False):
    do_something()
```

is (almost) equivalent to:

```
chainer.config.train = False
try:
    do_something()
finally:
    chainer.config.train = True
```

See also: https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/configuration.html#changing-configuration

Comment: Thanks you.I worked by using with chainer.using_config('train', False):
I should use chainer.config.train = False instead of command  chainer.using_config('train', False)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please upload the full stack-trace?
I'm very interested in where from the error was raised.

If it is from "chainer/links/normalization/batch_normalization.py", line 271~273, the error can be attributed to `chainer.config.train == True`.

In other cases, something wrong is happening.

Or, you can try
    print("chainer.config.train")
just before your call of `L.BatchNormalization`.